# How to set conditional value inside of an object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save code by making a conditional value inside set state object for for some reason my code is refusing to compile ? how to inject the conditional value as a value to a dynamic key?

```js
if (value === 'foo') {
  setErr({ ...inicialErrState,
    // specific value has an array the others only boolean
    fixedValue: [true, '']
  });
} else {
  setErr({ ...inicialErrState,
    [value]: true
  });
}


// Not working 
setErr({ ...inicialErrState,
  (errArr: value === 'fixedValue' ? [true, ''] : true)
});

// Not working 
setErr({ ...inicialErrState,
  value === 'fixedValue' ? {
    fixedValue: [true, '']
  } : {
    [value]: true
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
setErr({ 
  ...inicialErrState, 
  ...(value === 'foo' ? { [value]: true } : { fixedValue: [true, ''] })
})
```